# profile and user related

Tags: tab

Below are my questions and scenario:

As a Operations User, I need the Service Contract Status to reflect the status of its line items. I wrote a trigger and it is working in sandbox, and in QA sandbox as long I am system admin, But in order to test it in QA sandbox, when I log in as operation user, I dont see service contract tab there.

If I make service contract tab available for operation user, then will the problem solved ?
2nd question: Service contract, contract line items, assets and products all are related. Do I have to make visible all tab for operation user to see the service contract detail page along with line items and assets or whatever records are related ?

Comment: You just need to make sure the `Service Contract` tab/object is not hidden for that profile. The other objects are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the response,  I did, but I cannot test it because there is no record and no option to create records. What will be basic object permission? View All or modify all ? Do I have give basic access like view all to contract line item as well ?

Comment: Assuming Operations User has a different profile than SystemAdministrator then use Profile Settings to grant visibility to tab and CRUD access to `ServiceContract`. If only some Operations users need access, then use Permission Sets. `ContractLineItem` will get permissions from `ServiceContract` as it is master-detail.  View all/modify all means user can see/update any Service Contract - this may be OK or too broad - depends on business use case